# Evaluation order in DensityPlot

Tags: plotting

I have a module that, when given a value of the variable `a`, returns a function of the variable `x`. My actual problem is longer and more complicated; here I merely provide an MWE, say:

```
TestModule[a_] := 
 Module[{}, {vals, sols} = 
   NDEigensystem[{D[\[Phi][u], {u, 2}] + 1/u D[\[Phi][u], {u, 1}] - 
      1/u^2 \[Phi][u] - 1/4 a^2 u^2 \[Phi][u], 
     DirichletCondition[\[Phi][u] == 0, u == 1]}, \[Phi][u], {u, 0, 
     1}, 5, Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
        "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 10^-3}}}]; Return[\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(5\)]\(
\*FractionBox[\(0.01\), \(
\*SuperscriptBox[\((x - vals[\([\)\(i\)\(]\)])\), \(2\)] + 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(0.01\), \(2\)]\)] sols[\([i]\)]\)\) /. {u -> 0}, 
   Module];]
```

For instance (just to make things concrete), `TestModule[0.5]` returns

```
2.51604*10^-6/(0.0001 + (14.7028 + x)^2) + 5.4659*10^-6/(
 0.0001 + (49.2393 + x)^2) + 8.92959*10^-6/(
 0.0001 + (103.52 + x)^2) - 0.0000128153/(
 0.0001 + (177.542 + x)^2) + 0.0000170653/(0.0001 + (271.302 + x)^2)
```

I would now like to make a `DensityPlot` in the variables `a` and `x`. However, if I write

```
DensityPlot[Evaluate@TestModule[a],{a,0,1},{x,-500,0}]
```

I get the error `` "The PDE coefficient 1/u^2+(a^2\u^2)/4 does not evaluate to a numeric scalar at the coordinate {0.5}; it evaluated to 4. +0.0625` a^2  instead" ``. Naively it seems to me that `DensityPlot` is assuming I have an explicit expression in terms of `a` and then trying to evaluate the function, but this obviously fails at the level of DEigensystem. Instead, I would like that for each input of `a` that `DensityPlot` feeds the module, a function of `x` is obtained and then evaluated at the different values of `x`. Is there a way to ensure this and let `DensityPlot` first obtain the function of `x` for each given `a`, and only then evaluate at `x`? Please note that my actual problem is much more complicated and I would like to only evaluate the module once for each given `a`. I guess it all boils down to somehow modifying the evaluation order of `DensityPlot`. So ideally I'd like it to focus individually on each vertical slice, and then perform many of these slices corresponding to different values of `a`. Hopefully what I'm asking makes sense. Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037 might be helpful here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I did not come across that post before and I'll read through everything else as well as it seems very useful. Writing ```TestModule[a_?NumericQ]``` in the definition does give a working ```DensityPlot```. The problem is that then that the function gets evaluated at every pair ```(a,x)```. I really need it to only evaluated once at each ```a``` and then evaluate at ```x```, otherwise the plot in my actual problem will take literally days to complete. Perhaps this is not possible with ```DensityPlot``` itself and I have to find an alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given system doesn't actually show much variation over the range given. Let us rewrite the system to allow memoization:

```
TestModule[a_] := TestModule[a] =
   Module[{}, {vals, sols} = 
       NDEigensystem[{D[φ[u], {u, 2}] + 1/u D[φ[u], {u, 1}] - 
             1/u^2 φ[u] - 1/4 a^2 u^2 φ[u], 
           DirichletCondition[φ[u] == 0, u == 1]}, φ[u], {u, 0, 1}, 5, 
     Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
                 "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 10^-3}}}];
   Evaluate[Total[0.01/((# - vals)^2 + 0.01^2) (sols /. u -> 0)]] &]
```

Note that the return format is generalized slightly from the previous `Sum` notation, removed from the `Return` statement, and is returned as a function rather than an expression containing `x`. As an example:

```
TestModule[0.5]
```

> 2.51604*10^-6/(0.0001 + (14.7028 + #1)^2) + 5.4659*10^-6/(
> 0.0001 + (49.2393 + #1)^2) + 8.92959*10^-6/(
> 0.0001 + (103.52 + #1)^2) - 0.0000128153/(
> 0.0001 + (177.542 + #1)^2) + 0.0000170653/(
> 0.0001 + (271.302 + #1)^2) &

Specific `x` points can be extracted from this result as such: `TestModule[0.5][x]`.

This allows the evaluation of `a` once for a large range of `x`. For example, after clearing `` Global`* ``, evaluation of `Plot[TestModule[0.5][x], {x, -500, 0}]` takes about a tenth of a second on my machine, resulting in:

> [image: plot of the result of TestModule at a=0.5].

It is also possible to generate a density plot by manually sampling the various `a` values, e.g.:

```
AbsoluteTiming[dat = Table[{a, x, TestModule[a][x]}, {a, 0, 1, 0.1}, {x, -500, 0, 0.5}];]
```

> {0.616687, Null}

Relatively quick on my machine, for the number of points being generated here. Since the peaks are relatively narrow in `x`, the small step in `x` is chosen for ease of use. Nicer sampling techniques could probably use quite a smaller number of points though.

This can be plotted using `ListDensityPlot`:

```
ldp = ListDensityPlot[Flatten[dat, 1]];
ldp
```

> [image: density plot for x=-500 to 0 and a=0 to 1]

There is not much variation in the result observed over the small range of `a`.

Comment: Thank you for this! Not much variation in ```a``` is perfectly possible since I just made up this precise differential equation for the MWE :)